# What's the point of map in Haskell, when there is fmap?

Tags: haskell

Everywhere I've tried using `map`, `fmap` has worked as well. Why did the creators of Haskell feel the need for a `map` function? Couldn't it just be what is currently known as `fmap` and `fmap` could be removed from the language?

Comment: I think you are asking 'What's the point of fmap in Haskell'?

Comment: I know what the point of `fmap` is. It's to map a function over a Functor instance. I'm wondering abou8t the purpose of the specialization to `map`.

Comment: Similarly what is the point of `(.)` when there is `fmap` (tongue in cheek).

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I would like to make an answer to draw attention to [augustss's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824255/whats-the-point-of-map-in-haskell-when-there-is-fmap#comment-8112310):

> That's not actually how it happens. What happened was that the type of map was generalized to cover Functor in Haskell 1.3. I.e., in Haskell 1.3 fmap was called map. This change was then reverted in Haskell 1.4 and fmap was introduced. The reason for this change was pedagogical; when teaching Haskell to beginners the very general type of map made error messages more difficult to understand. In my opinion this wasn't the right way to solve the problem.

Haskell 98 is seen as a step backwards by some Haskellers (including me), previous versions having defined a more abstract and consistent library.  Oh well.

Comment: Are these backward steps collected and documented anywhere?  It would be interesting to see what else was considered a back step and if there are better solutions to them as well.

Comment: The `map and fmap` has been around for a long time - it was reheated on the Haskell-prime mailing list in August 2006 - http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-prime/2006-August/thread.html. As a counterpoint, I prefer the status quo. To me, it seems valuable that there's a subset of Haskell that corresponds roughly to Miranda. In the UK, Miranda was used as a teaching language for maths students not just computer science students. If that niche isn't already lost to a non-functional language (e.g. Mathematica) I don't see Haskell with a unified `map` filling it.

Comment: And I would further like to note, for anyone not already aware, that augustss is Lennart Augustsson, who for all practical purposes has been part of the Haskell community since before Haskell existed, cf. [A History of Haskell](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/history-of-haskell/index.htm), so the comment in question is not in any way second-hand hearsay!

Comment: There is now [Nitpicks page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Nitpicks) on Haskell wiki where this issue is mentioned.

Comment: It's funny that this decision was made for pedagogical reasons, because I confused fmap with flatmap all the time when learning Haskell. They should have gotten a n00b focusgroup together. :)

Answer (score 37):

Quoting from the `Functor` documentation at https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia#Functor

> You might ask why we need a separate `map` function. Why not just do
>   away with the current list-only `map` function, and rename `fmap` to `map`
>   instead? Well, that’s a good question. The usual argument is that
>   someone just learning Haskell, when using `map` incorrectly, would much
>   rather see an error about lists than about `Functor`.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me.

Comment: So this should've been a GHC hint, not a new function...

Answer (score 35):

They look the same on the application site but they're different, of course. When you apply either of those two functions, `map` or `fmap`, to a list of values they will produce the same result but that doesn't mean they're meant for the same purpose.

Run a GHCI session (the Glasgow Haskell Compiler Interactive) to query for information about those two functions, then have a look at their implementations and you will discover many differences.

#### map

Query GHCI for information about `map`

```
Prelude> :info map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]   -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

and you'll see it defined as an high-order function applicable to a list of values of any type `a` yielding a list of values of any type `b`. Although polymorphic (the `a` and `b` in the above definition stand for any type) the `map` function is intended to be applied to a **list of values** which is just one possible data type amongst many others in Haskell. The `map` function could not be applied to something which is not a list of values.

As you can read from the [GHC.Base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#map) source code, the `map` function is implemented as follows

```hs
map _ []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

which makes use of pattern matching to pull the head (the `x`) off the tail (the `xs`) of the list, then constructs a new list by using the `:` (cons) value constructor so to prepend `f x` (read it as *"f applied to x"*) to the recursion of `map` over the tail until the list is empty. It's worth noticing that the implementation of the `map`function does not rely upon any other function but just on itself.

#### fmap

Now try to query for information about `fmap` and you'll see something quite different.

```
Prelude> :info fmap
class Functor (f :: * -> *) where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
  ...
  -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

This time `fmap` is defined as one of the functions whose implementations must be provided by those data types which wish to belong to the `Functor` type class. That means that there can be more than one data types, not only the *"list of values"* data type, able to provide an implementation for the `fmap` function. That makes `fmap` applicable to a much larger set of data types: the functors indeed!

As you can read from the [GHC.Base](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-711) source code, a possible implementation of the `fmap` function is the one provided by the `Maybe` data type:

```hs
instance  Functor Maybe  where
  fmap _ Nothing       = Nothing
  fmap f (Just a)      = Just (f a)
```

and another possible implementation is the one provided by the 2-tuple data type

```hs
instance Functor ((,) a) where
  fmap f (x,y) = (x, f y)
```

and another possible implementation is the one provided by the list data type (of course!):

```hs
instance  Functor []  where
  fmap f xs = map f xs
```

which relies upon the `map` function.

#### Conclusion

The `map` function can be applied to nothing more than list of values (where values are of any type) whereas the `fmap` function can be applied much more data types: all of those which belongs to the functor class (e.g. maybes, tuples, lists, etc.). Since the *"list of values"* data type is also a functor (because it provides an implementation for it) then `fmap` can be applied to is as well producing the very same result as `map`.

```hs
map  (+3) [1..5]
fmap (+3) (Just 15)
fmap (+3) (5, 7)
```